# Css não muda a cor para transparente

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tenho um menu de um site onde especionando o elemento eu mudo para uma cor transparente mais ele nao muda, mesmo colocando como !important na frente da propriedade.
Veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse menu ele esta assim no meu style.css

```
.navigation{
height:50px;
background:rgba(243, 241, 245, 0.04) !important;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
z-index:2;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

no background esta ja em transparente mais mesmo assim, quando eu recarrego a pagina ele volta para a cor :

```
    background: #f8f7f3;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem ideia o por que não segura o valor rgb que ue coloco?

Comment: transparente e `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Não tudo bem mais mesmo eu colocando rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); ele ainda nao fica. Parece que tem outra regra por traz

Comment: posta o codigo ta meio esquisito

Comment: Mais meu css tem 3000 linhas. entao eu coloquei ai somente onde ele acusa quando eu inspeciono o elemento. 
da uma olhada ai na classe navigation

Comment: Limpa o cache. xD

Comment: do html na area que está usando;

Comment: Limpei o cache e nada

Comment: Ops, man. Quando vc me falou em html, eu tive a ideia de aplicar na propria pagina onde esta o meu menu. agora sim.

Comment: @usuario Existe uma diferença entre "transparente" e "invisível".

Comment: @Dvdsamm existe mesmo mas se deixar o `.navigation` invisível vai sumir o menu dele.

Comment: @usuario Mas ele quer um alpha 0.04. Se colocar 0 no alpha vai ficar com transparência total e ficar invisível.

Comment: @Dvdsamm o background vai ficar transparente total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver essa questão, na própria pagina onde esta incorporada o menu, aplica a transparencia chamando a chasse referente ao menu.
veja:

```
<style>
.navigation{
    background:rgba(243, 241, 245, 0.04) !important;
}
</style>
```

Forçando assim o css aplicar a ultima regra feita na página onde esta o menu.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar o CSS *inline* direto no elemento com `style`. Isso ignora todas as referências do estilo `background` ao elemento vindo de algum CSS:

```
<div class="navigation" style="background:rgba(243, 241, 245, 0.04);"></div>
```